# How to properly dynamically import modules in packages for developing / testing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made an app with lots of packages and modules. I'm developing these packages (within their directories) and since I'm executing files within the package directory the import paths for modules/packages change.

For instance, the project looks a little bit like this...

```
├── app.py
└── utils
    ├── database.py
    └── robot
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── run.py
        ├── recognition.py
        └── housekeeping.py
```

If I executed `python3 app.py` then `import utils.database` is valid.

But if I was in the package and ran `python3 run.py` then `import utils.database` is *not* valid.

I want to know how to execute functions and import the modules/packages without getting an error.

---

I have got this working, but I don't think it is right. So far, I've tried using `__name__ == "__main__"` in every main `.py` file and using `sys.path.append`, but I feel like there must be an easier better-looking way.

This is what the inside of `run.py` looks like, I also had to do the same in `database.py`, is this the best way?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.path.append('../../')

from utils.robot.recognition import *
from utils.robot.housekeeping import *
import utils.database as db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the directory containing `utils`, then your imports will work.

Never run a module contained within a package directly.  It's problematic if the same is run directly and can also be imported from the package, because then there will be two copies of the module in the interpreter, which guarantees confusion.

Instead, use the `-m` interpreter option:

```
python -m utils.robot.run
```

Alternatively, if you never need to import run.py from other modules, you can remove the file from the package entirely and keep it in a separate 'scripts' directory, and then you don't need to use `-m`.  But you still need to set up sys.path, either using `$PYTHONPATH` as before, or by doing sys.path manipulations.  If you choose to do sys.path manipulations, then you should make it work regardless of what the current working directory is:

```py
 sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../'))
```